# C# - прогресс подготовки PrintPreviewDialog

Tags: c#

Делаю приложение, которое работает поверх SCADA-системы. SCADA развернута на весь экран, Alt-Tab заблокирован, поэтому приложение всегда должно быть поверх всех окон - выставил `TopMost`. Пользователь может запросить на печать информацию из приложения, получает превью, подтверждает печать и документ печатается.

Для работы с печатью использую `PrintDocument` и `PrintPreviewDialog`. `PrintPreviewDialog` тоже не должен упасть за скаду, поэтому тоже выставил ему `TopMost`. Но при обработке большого объема данных появляется окно "Прогресс подготовки к предварительному просмотру", которое остается под `PrintPreviewDialog`. В то же время отменить обработку можно только с окна с отображением прогресса. Если в момент обработки попытаться закрыть превью, то приложение отмечается как не отвечающее и крашится все приложение.

Возможно ли с теми компонентами, что я использую сделать так - вывести превью, вывести прогресс обработки поверх всего, запретить делать что-либо с превью пока прогресс не закончился или его не отменили?